# ayuda con la consulta sql

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

tengo un inconveniente la consulta para realizar paginación, corre normal en `sql-server`, pero creo que no en php y es para simular `LIMIT`, no se interpreta correctamente.

Aquí la consulta es:

```php
public function
paginador_administrador($pagina,$registros,$privilegio,$codigo){

$pagina=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($pagina);
$privilegio=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($privilegio);
$codigo=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($codigo);
$tabla="";
$pagina= (isset($pagina) && $pagina>0) ? (int) $pagina : 1;
$inicio= ($pagina>0) ? (($pagina*$registros)-$registros) : 0;
$conexion = mainModel::conectar();

$qery="WITH ADMINISTRADORES AS";
$qery.="(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY APELLIDOS ASC) AS
TotalReg,DNI,NOMBRES,APELLIDOS,PERFIL,C AS CELULAR, F AS FIJO,ESTADO
FROM (SELECT P.numeroId_Per AS DNI,P.Nombre_Per as
NOMBRES, P.ApellidosPat_Per + ' ' + P.ApellidosMat_Per as
APELLIDOS,tipo_Tel, T.numero_Tel AS TELEFONO, CASE WHEN id_perfil=1
THEN 'ADMINISTRADOR' WHEN id_perfil=2 THEN 'DOCENTE' WHEN
id_perfil=3 THEN 'DIRECTOR' END AS PERFIL ,
CASE WHEN estado_us=0 THEN 'NO HABIL' WHEN estado_us=1 THEN 'HABIL'
END AS ESTADO
from UsuarioSistema US
INNER JOIN Persona P ON US.identificador_Per = P.identificador_Per
INNER JOIN Docente D ON P.identificador_Per = D.identificador_Per
JOIN Telefono T ON P.identificador_Per = T.identificador_Per
WHERE id_perfil <> 1 AND codigo_Peri=97)DOCTEL
    PIVOT (

    MAX(TELEFONO)
    FOR tipo_Tel IN ([C],[F])

    ) TELDOCPIVOT)";
    $datos = $conexion->query($qery."SELECT * FROM ADMINISTRADORES WHERE
    TotalReg BETWEEN ".'$inicio'." AND ".'$registros');

    $consulta1=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT
    COUNT(identificador_Doc)-1 AS nrofilas FROM Docente WHERE
    codigo_Peri=97")->fetch();

    $total=$consulta1['nrofilas'];
    $Npaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

    if($total>=1 && $pagina<=$Npaginas){ $contador=$inicio+1; foreach ($datos as $rows) { # code... } } console.log("TCL: php public function paginador_administrador($pagina,$registros,$privilegio,$codigo){ $pagina=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($pagina); $privilegio=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($privilegio); $codigo=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($codigo); $tabla="" ; $pagina=(isset($pagina) && $pagina>0) ? (int) $pagina : 1;
        $inicio= ($pagina>0) ? (($pagina*$registros)-$registros) : 0;
        $conexion = mainModel::conectar();

        $qery="WITH ADMINISTRADORES AS";
        $qery.="(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY APELLIDOS ASC) AS
        TotalReg,DNI,NOMBRES,APELLIDOS,PERFIL,C AS CELULAR, F AS FIJO,ESTADO
        FROM (SELECT P.numeroId_Per AS DNI,P.Nombre_Per as
        NOMBRES, P.ApellidosPat_Per + ' ' + P.ApellidosMat_Per as
        APELLIDOS,tipo_Tel, T.numero_Tel AS TELEFONO, CASE WHEN id_perfil=1
        THEN 'ADMINISTRADOR' WHEN id_perfil=2 THEN 'DOCENTE' WHEN
        id_perfil=3 THEN 'DIRECTOR' END AS PERFIL ,
        CASE WHEN estado_us=0 THEN 'NO HABIL' WHEN estado_us=1 THEN 'HABIL'
        END AS ESTADO
        from UsuarioSistema US
        INNER JOIN Persona P ON US.identificador_Per = P.identificador_Per
        INNER JOIN Docente D ON P.identificador_Per = D.identificador_Per
        JOIN Telefono T ON P.identificador_Per = T.identificador_Per
        WHERE id_perfil <> 1 AND codigo_Peri=97)DOCTEL
            PIVOT (

            MAX(TELEFONO)
            FOR tipo_Tel IN ([C],[F])

            ) TELDOCPIVOT)";
            $datos = $conexion->query($qery."SELECT * FROM ADMINISTRADORES WHERE
            TotalReg BETWEEN ".'$inicio'." AND ".'$registros');

            $consulta1=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT
            COUNT(identificador_Doc)-1 AS nrofilas FROM Docente WHERE
            codigo_Peri=97")->fetch();

            $total=$consulta1['nrofilas'];
            $Npaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

            if($total>=1 && $pagina<=$Npaginas){ $contador=$inicio+1; foreach ($datos as $rows) { # code... } } }", php public function paginador_administrador($pagina,$registros,$privilegio,$codigo){ $pagina=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($pagina); $privilegio=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($privilegio); $codigo=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($codigo); $tabla="" ; $pagina=(isset($pagina) && $pagina>0) ? (int) $pagina : 1;
                $inicio= ($pagina>0) ? (($pagina*$registros)-$registros) : 0;
                $conexion = mainModel::conectar();

                $qery="WITH ADMINISTRADORES AS";
                $qery.="(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY APELLIDOS ASC) AS
                TotalReg,DNI,NOMBRES,APELLIDOS,PERFIL,C AS CELULAR, F AS FIJO,ESTADO
                FROM (SELECT P.numeroId_Per AS DNI,P.Nombre_Per as
                NOMBRES, P.ApellidosPat_Per + ' ' + P.ApellidosMat_Per as
                APELLIDOS,tipo_Tel, T.numero_Tel AS TELEFONO, CASE WHEN id_perfil=1
                THEN 'ADMINISTRADOR' WHEN id_perfil=2 THEN 'DOCENTE' WHEN
                id_perfil=3 THEN 'DIRECTOR' END AS PERFIL ,
                CASE WHEN estado_us=0 THEN 'NO HABIL' WHEN estado_us=1 THEN 'HABIL'
                END AS ESTADO
                from UsuarioSistema US
                INNER JOIN Persona P ON US.identificador_Per = P.identificador_Per
                INNER JOIN Docente D ON P.identificador_Per = D.identificador_Per
                JOIN Telefono T ON P.identificador_Per = T.identificador_Per
                WHERE id_perfil <> 1 AND codigo_Peri=97)DOCTEL
                    PIVOT (

                    MAX(TELEFONO)
                    FOR tipo_Tel IN ([C],[F])

                    ) TELDOCPIVOT)";
                    $datos = $conexion->query($qery."SELECT * FROM ADMINISTRADORES WHERE
                    TotalReg BETWEEN ".'$inicio'." AND ".'$registros');

                    $consulta1=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT
                    COUNT(identificador_Doc)-1 AS nrofilas FROM Docente WHERE
                    codigo_Peri=97")->fetch();

                    $total=$consulta1['nrofilas'];
                    $Npaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

                    if($total>=1 && $pagina<=$Npaginas){ $contador=$inicio+1; foreach ($datos as $rows) { # code... } } }) }
```

me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs.....

por favor si pueden ayudarme y aclararme las dudas.
muchas gracias

Comment: Parece que la variable $datos pasada por el foreach no es un iterable, por favor verifica que la consulta "SELECT * FROM ADMINISTRADORES WHERE 
        TotalReg BETWEEN ".'$inicio'." AND ".'$registros'" te retorne información.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de la gente con el código formateado? Tener un código con un buen formato ayuda a prevenir y encontrar errores.

Comment: buenos días al parecer la consulta no responde desde el PHP y creo q ese es el problema @Anibal Ospina

Comment: no se como estructurarla o escribirla dentro de php, al parecer no devuelve los resultados, alguien que pueda ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: Listo lo solucione gracias por ayudar en el formateo del código era eso y cambiar fetch por fetchAll(). Gracias